# Best OS for mining Monero on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: operating-systems, terminal

Currently I'm mining Monero on the raspberry pi (for educational purposes and not profitable).

Short input on Monero:

- only CPU performance matters
- GPU and RAM can/should be neglected
- mining is terminal based (cli)

What I'm looking for is an OS that is terminal based (and fast!!!)

As I have no experienced in OS so
 **which OS do you prefer for cli based tasks?**

Comment: This question is awkward in that it asks for opinions. The raspberry pi forum is more suited to that style of interaction. That said, I would suggest that the job of the OS is simply to call your mining program. I.e., your programming language choice will matter more than the OS. Specifically, consider coding in multithreaded C++ perhaps even in assembly to get the highest hashrate.

Comment: *"RAM can/should be neglected"* -> Since that's where all the code and information that goes through the CPU is, this would be contra the goal of performance.  But that is really much more about hardware.  As to which Pi OS would run a particular application the fastest, it most likely will be about particulars of the application and not generalizations about the OS.  The most common Pi OS's are GNU/Linux variants and **they are all identical WRT the criteria in your question.**  As to whether they are better than other options (Window IoT, FreeBSD, RISC...), that's really a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS does not matter, use whatever is already installed on your RPi, or download whatever image you like, Raspbian or anything else.

Google for "monero miner source", the first URL on the top of the list would be [GitHub - xmrig/xmrig: Monero (XMR) CPU miner](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig), download the code, compile it and run.

Once you did that, you may come back here and explain if you encounter any problems, and maybe then someone will tell you how to solve those. Because nobody wants to do your homework for you, you have to do it yourself.

A few footnotes:

1. The performance on RPi is going to be abysmal. You'd get much better return for your money if you just buy $50 (what's the price of your RPi) worth of XMR and let the price go up.
2. You might be better off downloading and compiling the miner on PC first, it's faster and likely you'll encounter less problems. Then you may port things to RPi.
3. Next time you ask the question, you need to include 4 important parts: 1) what you try to achieve, 2) what did you do 3) what result did you expect and 4) what result did you get and what went wrong.